# GeoserverTerrainProvider plugin displays faults in elevation tiles

Tags: geoserver, gdal, dem, openlayers, cesium

I try to display elevation data using the triple Geoserver/Openlayer3/Cesium. It seems I have the same problem than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936968 and for now, I can not get a working solution!

I have done nearly the same gdal processing to obtain my picture pyramid and whatever the GeoserverTerrainProvider solution I use (BIL or with SLD) I get sharp cut elevation at tile edges (see: http://postimg.org/image/wy0j1ijnp/)

In the geoserver layer preview, my elevation image as bad tile border in 'Tiling: Tiled' mode but is ok in 'Single tile' mode. This may be the cause of my problems: ie. GeoserverTerrainProvider is badly requesting tiles from geoserver?

Or did I fail at generating the pyramid geotiff?

Comment: I post the bash script I use to create the pyramid http://pastebin.com/rK2ctBnL

Comment: Does the terrain data display ok in GeoServer itself (Layer Preview)? As a TMS? What about as  WMS? If you created it properly it should work fine in there. Then it becomes a plugin issue.

Comment: Here is the layer preview in tiled mode: http://postimg.org/image/8sff9lw71/. I am accessing it (or the plugin is) by WMS not by TMS. I will post a question to the plugin manager...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved using the good gdal commands:

`gdalwarp -ot Int16 -s_srs "EPSG:2154" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -dstnodata -32762 -r cubicspline -multi -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "ZLEVEL=6" *.asc outFolder/gray.tif`

`gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 3 -ps 2048 2048 -ot Int16 -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "ZLEVEL=6" -targetDir pyramidFolder outFolder/gray.tif`

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cesium-dev/6aR35AuZ0mM/mVWaeKsPqg8J for the details.